# Time Elapsed To Continue Even After Declaring In JS

Tags: javascript

I have a code here in which the value of imgNumb is defined by timeElapsed variable. As the time goes by the value of imgNumb starting from 0 goes to max of 4 after which I would like it to start back from 0 again; like in a loop. The function which does most of the work is autoFade().

**Problem:** The problem is after I declare elapsedTime equal to delay it remains 4 only for rest of the duration and does not increase like before.

Please help me! if you can, I would really appreciate it! Thanks.

And here is the code below:

```
var a = document.getElementById("slidermain");
var b = a.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
var len = b.length;

var cusOpac = 0;
var delay = 4;
var imgNumb = 0;
var elem;
var now, before = new Date();

function autoFade(){
    var loop = setInterval(function(){
    now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());
    var elapsedTime = Math.floor(timeDiff/1000);
    var lendelay = len*delay;
    var currentFrame = Math.floor(elapsedTime/delay)-1;
    var imgNumb = currentFrame % 5;
    initFade(imgNumb);
    }, delay*1000); 
}

function initFade(imgNumb){
    elem = b[imgNumb];
    startFadeEffect(elem);
}

function startFadeEffect(elem){
    opacSetting = cusOpac / 10;
    elem.style.opacity = opacSetting;   
    elem.style.display = "block";
    cusOpac++;
    if(cusOpac > 10){
         cusOpac = 10;  
    }
    var timer = setTimeout(function() { startFadeEffect(elem); }, 55);
    if(opacSetting == 1){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        cusOpac = 10;
        elem.style.opacity = 1;
        setTimeout(function() { endFadeEffect(elem); }, (delay*1000)/2);
    }
}

function endFadeEffect(elem){
    opacSetting = cusOpac / 10;
    elem.style.opacity = opacSetting;
    cusOpac--;
    if(cusOpac < 0){
        cusOpac = 0;    
    }
    var timer = setTimeout(function() { endFadeEffect(elem); }, 55);
    if(opacSetting == 0){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        elem.style.opacity = 0;
        elem.style.display = "none";
        cusOpac = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Please note I am looking for a javascript only solution!***

Comment: You're already running an interval every 4 seconds, so why do you keep running a rather expensive operation (calculating the difference in time - it'll always be ~4000 milliseconds after the last run) rather than simply adding 1 to a variable and resetting it once it reaches 4?

Comment: I am using it as a timer for my FadeIn and Out animation which I have created in the next functions. So, that the animation keeps running even if the tab of the browser is not active.

Answer (score 0):

Please format the code properly and try to reduce it to the absolute minimum necessary. In your case I believe you're asking to create a function `f(elapsedTimeSeconds)` -> `imgNumb`, that works like this:

- If `delay * 0 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 1`, `imgNumb` = 0
- If `delay * 1 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 2`, `imgNumb` = 0
- If `delay * 2 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 3`, `imgNumb` = 1
- If `delay * 3 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 4`, `imgNumb` = 2
- If `delay * 4 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 5`, `imgNumb` = 3
- If `delay * 5 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 6`, `imgNumb` = 4
- If `delay * 6 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 7`, `imgNumb` = 0
- If `delay * 7 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay * 8`, `imgNumb` = 1

...and so on.

You have already figured out that `Math.floor(elapsedTimeSeconds/delay)-1` gives you what you need if `delay*1 <= elapsedTimeSeconds < delay*6`, but after that it continues to grow.

So what you need is a function that produces:

- 0 -> 0
- ...
- 4 -> 4
- 5 -> 0
- 6 -> 1
- ...
- 9 -> 4

.. and so on. That's the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
 var currentFrame = Math.floor(elapsedTimeSeconds/delay)-1;
 var imgNumb = currentFrame % 5;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am going through the modulo operation now, but what does the last 2 lines of code u have mentioned do exactly?

Comment: @SameerBakshi they are a solution to the problem I guessed you needed to solve (*"I believe you're asking to create a function f(elapsedTimeSeconds) -> imgNumb, that works like this"*). The idea is that given the starting time, the current time, and the delay between "frames" (i.e. moments when something changes on the page), we can find the frame number - that's the first line. It will grow indefinitely (0, 1, 2, ..., 11, 12). Next, we need to convert that to the image number that must repeat from 0 to 4, over and over. For that we use the modulo (% 5).

Comment: okay but wat happens when elapseTime is greater than lendelay? And thanks again!

Comment: @SameerBakshi that's the problem with the original code, I can only guess what `lendelay` is. Assuming, `lendelay` is the duration it takes to loop through all the images, `elapsedTime>lendelay` is when currentFrame becomes >5, and when you start to need the modulo operator. If you go this route, you don't need the `if`.

Comment: Okay thanks now I understand the concept you are trying to convey. However, the problem for which I had used a timer to check on my fadein and fadeout function in my image slider has not been solved. I have updated the JS code in the question above to the full code I am using can you suggest me what is going wrong? My problem is that when I browse through other tabs while the slider is running, the setInterval function or setTimeout function(s) stop working. I want to resolve this, but so far have been unsuccessful. Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: I am a newbie here and to JS. If you need HTML as well let me know!

Comment: Sorry, I'm done for today. Anyways this seems unrelated, and I think you'll have better chances if you ask a new question. Do provide the testcase, otherwise it's hard to see what you're talking about (what other tabs? what slider? Why do you think that setInterval or setTimeout stop working?). Also perhaps if you stated the original problem you're trying to solve, you'd get better end result, the way you're doing animation is only good for learning to do this without libraries.

Comment: In case you were talking about switching to other tabs in the  *browser*, note that [Timeouts in inactive tabs are clamped to >=1000ms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Timeouts_in_inactive_tabs_clamped_to_%3E1000ms)

Comment: Okay thanks! I will try to post a new question tomorrow. Thanks for your help!